# better way of doing .html("").append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a message-slot in the page, I show different messages in it. For each message I run the template and I append that HTML to messageslot like this. I add html("") to clear the box first. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
$("#message-slot").html("").append(messagetemplate);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
$("#message-slot").html(messagetemplate);
```

It will clear any existing contents before replacing them ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/html/)):

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

As a side note, be mindful of any existing event handlers that might be attached to elements you're removing. You'll want to be sure to unbind them. See [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) for more info.

Comment: jquery documentation says .html appends htmlstring only, where as append can have jquery elements as well.

Comment: @sublime: You can most certainly use jQuery objects with `html()`.